# How to move the text cursor forward?

Tags: c

We can add **'\n'** character to a string so that it can go to next line when we use  `printf`.

Then, how to move the text cursor forward exactly one row?
As easy as we implement next line using **'\n'**.

For example, this is a string "I lie`\moveforwardk`k"

It should be "I like" when I output the string using `printf`.

Comment: You can't "move forward" if there's no text to move to. Are you sure you don't just want to as spaces or tabs?

Comment: Based on your edit, do you mean move backwards? In your example, you'd need to erase the 'k' using `\b` (the backspace character), then retype the 'e'.

Comment: Maybe what he wants is a carriage return `\r` but I am a bit confused by his question. And `\r` might not bring the expected result on some consoles.

Comment: But it's allowed to use printf("\b"), right?

Comment: @Byron Yes, `\b` acts as though you hit the backspace key. It doesn't work in every console though. It's the only way I know of to change what's already been printed though.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your "I like" example, I'm going to assume you meant move "backwards" instead of "forwards".

To the best of my knowledge, there's no super easy way to achieve what you're trying to do. You can't actually programatically move the cursor unless you simulate pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard. That assumes the console you're using supports moving the cursor though.

The closest method I know of is to use the backspace key (`\b`) to erase the "e", insert the "k", then retype the "e":

- Print "I lie".
- Print" "\b". This will erase the last character printed ("e").
- Print "ke".

Note, `\b` doesn't always work:

- It doesn't appear to work in REPLs, only full consoles.
- It can't erase anything that came before a newline (`\n`). Once you print a new line, you've "saved" everything on that line.

You can also use the system call "cls" to wipe the screen entirely, but that has poor compatibility too and requires you to retype everything, not just the last few characters.

---

I'll note that after looking over my answer a few years later, I'm actually wrong. You can in fact move the cursor. This can be done using ANSII escape codes, or a library that wraps over them like Curses. Unless you need that though, pushing a backspace is probably the easiest option.